# Switch/Case condition fails

Tags: c#, calculator

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)  

   { 
    bool WantToQuit = false;
    string action = "Quit";
    int currentNumber = 0;
    int number2 = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to work with:");
    currentNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    {
        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("1 - Add");
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Substract");
        Console.WriteLine("3 - Divide");
        Console.WriteLine("4 - Multiply");
        Console.WriteLine("5 - Modulus");  
        Console.WriteLine("6 - Quit");

        action = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter another number to manipulate the current number:");
        number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (action)
        {
            case "Add":
                currentNumber += number2;
                break;
            case "Substract":
                currentNumber -= number2;
                break;
            case "Divide":
                currentNumber /= number2;
                break;
            case "Multiply":
                currentNumber *= number2;
                break;
            case "Modulus":
                currentNumber %= number2;
                break;
            case "Quit":
                WantToQuit = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Current number = " + currentNumber);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("END OF PROGRAM");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

}

There are no such red code errors; however, when I execute the program it doesn't add the `currentNumber`. It will just say add another number you would want to manipulate and it would say the same number as the current number (original).

I feel like if I really was doing something wrong it would be within the

```
switch (action) 
{...}
```

but I can't figure it out. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: what are you passing as action?

Comment: First use debugger. See what happens step by step. Then attempt to ask questions.

Comment: Switch on a string is case sensitive.

Comment: The `switch` is done over the string `action`, and if I type "Add", I get the sum of the two values. Are you by chance typing "1" instead of the operation name **exactly** as in each `case`? Also note that `WantToQuit` is never used, there's no need to initialize `currentNumber` or `number2` as they are never used before their actual initialization, and the brackets just before "What would you like to do?" are not needed at all. (Perhaps you had a `while (WantToQuit)` there before).

Comment: Made a mistake, should have been like this:  case "1": // not have the word operation there
                                                                       currentNumber += number2;
                                                                       break;

Answer (score 2):

try case "1" instead case "Add"

Answer (score 1):

Following the @Mick's answer
Use it in such way

```
case "1":
case "Add":
break;
```

Comment: Thanks Umar! It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

During such situation, break point is your friend. You need to set them at certain location, best at the starting of your code to ensure the code run according to your expectation.

You have to use break point to verify your `currentNumber` and then your `action` variable to make sure they are returning the correct value for the rest of your code flow.